# I add buttons on scrollview but buttons are not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new in iphone.I added 10 buttons on the scrollview.Buttons are scroll properly,but only 5 buttons are working last five buttons are not working.please suggest me what i do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it could be one of two things

Either ...

1. There are no associated actions with the buttons (programatically or in IB)
2. There is another view that is covering the buttons and taking all the touch events

Try swapping the position of two of the buttons (one working and one not) and see if they continue to work as before. If they do, then it looks like the actions are not set up. If they have now changed, then there is an issue with where the buttons are placed.

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced such problems...I also think there will be another view which is covering that button and their touch events....